# how ping address from dynamic variable?

Tags: bash, eval, ping

I want to ping in a `for loop` using dynamic names.
When i try `ping -c1 -w1 10.0.0.10 > /dev/null` it works perfectly, but when i try to change my static adress into a dynamic one, i'll get an error.

```
declare -A array=([piotr_pc]=10.0.0.10 )

for item in ${!array[*]}
do
    file=$(grep $item homesystem/web/openvpn-status.log | tr 'm\n' 'p,')
    IFS=','
    for x in $file
    do          
        eval $item+=\("$x"\)
    done

    eval echo \${$item[9]}

    if ping -c1 -w1 eval echo \${$item[9]} > /dev/null; then
        echo eval echo \${$item[9]} "ONLINE" $NOW
        echo "UPDATE openvpn SET status='ONLINE', last_online='$NOW' , Common Name = '${piotr_pc[0]}', Real Address = '${piotr_pc[1]}', Bytes Received = '${piotr_pc[2]}', Bytes Sent = '${piotr_pc[3]}', Connected Since = '${piotr_pc[4]}', Virtual Address = '${piotr_pc[5]}' , Last Ref = '${piotr_pc[8]}' WHERE ip_vpn='${piotr_pc[5]}'"
        #mysql -uphptest -pphphaslo openwrt -e "UPDATE openvpn SET status='ONLINE', last_online='$NOW'  WHERE ip_vpn='$ip'"
    else
        eval echo \${$item[9]} "OFFLINE"
        #mysql -uphptest -pphphaslo openwrt -e "UPDATE openvpn SET status='OFFLINE' WHERE ip_vpn='$ip'"
    fi
done
```

Result:

```
root@VigoradoNetwork:/www1# ./ping.sh
10.0.0.10
BusyBox v1.28.3 () multi-call binary.

Usage: ping [OPTIONS] HOST

Send ICMP ECHO_REQUEST packets to network hosts

        -4,-6           Force IP or IPv6 name resolution
        -c CNT          Send only CNT pings
        -s SIZE         Send SIZE data bytes in packets (default 56)
        -t TTL          Set TTL
        -I IFACE/IP     Source interface or IP address
        -W SEC          Seconds to wait for the first response (default 10)
                        (after all -c CNT packets are sent)
        -w SEC          Seconds until ping exits (default:infinite)
                        (can exit earlier with -c CNT)
        -q              Quiet, only display output at start
                        and when finished
        -p HEXBYTE      Pattern to use for payload
10.0.0.10 OFFLINE
```

I want to change this `10.0.0.10` with `eval echo \${$item[9]}` but i dont know how to do this.

Comment: No offence, but this is horrible. Using `eval` is a code smell. You appear to be looping over the array but at the same time building the array. Show the contents of the openvpn-status.log file and please explain some more about exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: I trying get all data from openvpn log ping each ip from vpn client and add them status OFFLINE or ONLINE and put into base.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i understood you correctly but following may be helpful if you are running multiple pings to hosts using a hostlist file.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "`date` Starting the Ping Check...."

function pingHost () {
    hostTarget=${1}
    # send stdout/stderr to /dev/null since all we need is the return code
    ping -c2 ${hostTarget} >/dev/null 2>&1 &&
    echo Host ${hostTarget} is SUCCESS||
    echo Host ${hostTarget} is FAILED
}

data=$(<my_hostlist)  # Place your hostlist here example "Master_hostlist"
for line in ${data}
do
    # call our function and place the call in the background
    pingHost ${line} &
done
# wait for all outstanding background jobs to complete before continuing
wait
# [optional] let operator know we're done.
echo "Completed @=> `date`"
```

Comment: @glennjackman, i took it on my python indented editor, let me fix it.

Comment: fixed indentation.

Comment: A couple of notes: 1) [quote your variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/171346/4667); 2) [don't read lines with `for`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: ... [don't use `function foo ()`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#function_foo.28.29), [prefer `$(...)` over backticks](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082), [watch out with `cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3)